# Get scrollable height of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, window

First of all,I would like to know the difference between these terms:

```
- $(window).height() 

- $(document).height() 

- $(window).scrollTop()
```

These terms look somewhat similar to me and I am unable to understand the clear difference between them. Here are my answers:

- `$(window).height()` : Gives the height of window which a user can see.
- `$(document).height()` : Gives total height of document. This can be more/less than window height depending upon the content on the page.
- `$(document).scrollTop()` : gives the vertical position of scrollbar in window.

**Real Question:**
I am trying to implement lazy loading kinda thing where I need to make a call to server when scrollbar has crossed a point 200px from bottom of page. I am unable to use the above values to get this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I figured out what should be the calculations after understanding these terms. Thanks to the answers. I was almost right in my definitions.

```
function (isScrollable) {
  var isUserAtBottom = ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() + 200 > $(document).height());
  if (isUserAtBottom) {
     // Do something (Like Ajax call to server to fetch new elements) 
     return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The window is the area that you can see - as if your screen is a window and you are looking through at the document. The document is the entire document - it could be shorter or much longer than the window.

This is the math you need:

```
if( $(document).height() - $(document).scrollTop() < 200 ){
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
$(window).scrollTop(); //Get the current vertical position of the scroll bar for the first               element in the set of matched elements or set the vertical position of the scroll bar for every matched element.

$(window).scrollHeight(); //Height of the scroll view of an element; it includes the element padding but not its margin.
```

Comment: `$(window).scrollHeight()` whats that?